# How can install libX11 on aws lambda function

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, headless-browser

I have a python function which didn't work initially on cloud9(Amazon Linux2). After having installed libX11(the code uses headless chrome with selenium) the problem is gone. I just wanted to do the same on lambda so tried to add libX11 as a layer as explained in the link below but that didn't resolve the issue.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/.

[My packages are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x90IX.png)

I packaged them directly and didn't work, on my 2nd try i packaged them under /lib directory but not joy. I actually don't want docker as an option as it gives you no control on modification of the code. Any alternative guys?

Comment: How is this question related to _Selenium_?

Comment: Because if you want to use Selenium for headless chrome, which is one of the common use cases, requires libX11. Clear enough?